# Trying to traverse a .word "Table" in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I seem to be having a issue understanding part of the project my teacher assigned.

So the basic Idea is that I have a .word "table", Full of IP addresses. I need to be able to traverse the table and compare the different values and match the numbers up with user input.  I also need to account for any size table, not just the table that he gave us.
   I first tested out trying to get through the table first, because I have never worked with the .word before.  I figured out how to load the table, and how to use the offsets for one line, the issue is when I try to get to the next line.  I thought that I was supposed to use:

```
addi $a0, 20  
I have also tried the addu and add instructions.
```

This was to get to the next line, however I get to an Exception 4, which is a data fetch error.  This happens after I try to load a new word like:

```
lw $s0, ($a0)
```

I am not really sure what to do from here, I know that $a0 is getting incremented outside of where the table is, I am just unsure how to fix it or what the actual code should be.  Here is what I am using to test with.

```
.data

MESSAGE1: .asciiz "Enter an IP address\n"
MESSAGE2: .asciiz "First: "
MESSAGE3: .asciiz "Second: "
MESSAGE4: .asciiz "Third: "
MESSAGE5: .asciiz "Fourth: "
MESSAGE6: .asciiz "The IP address you enterd: "
MESSAGE7: .asciiz "."
MESSAGE8: .asciiz "\nClass A address\n"
MESSAGE9: .asciiz "\nClass B address\n"
MESSAGE10: .asciiz "\nClass C address\n"
MESSAGE11: .asciiz "\nClass D address\n"
MESSAGE12: .asciiz "\nInvalid domain class\n"
MESSAGE13: .asciiz "\nProgram successfully completed . . .\n"
MESSAGE14: .asciiz "\n"
MESSAGE15: .asciiz "Matching domain found at: "
MESSAGE16: .asciiz "Matching domain was NOT found . . . \n"
ERROROVER: .asciiz "The entered number is larger than 255.\n"
ERRORUNDER: .asciiz "The entered number is smaller than 0.\n"
ERROR: .asciiz "Invalid Number detected make sure the number entered is 
between 0 and 255."
IP_ROUTING_TABLE_SIZE:
    .word   10

IP_ROUTING_TABLE:
    # line #, x.x.x.x -------------------------------------
    .word   0, 146,  92, 255, 255   # 146.92.255.255
    .word   1, 147, 163, 255, 255   # 147.163.255.255
    .word   2, 201,  88,  88,  90   # 201.88.88.90
    .word   3, 182, 151,  44,  56   # 182.151.44.56
    .word   4,  24, 125, 100, 100   # 24.125.100.100
    .word   5, 146, 163, 140,  80   # 146.163.170.80
    .word   6, 146, 163, 147,  80   # 146.163.147.80
    .word  10, 201,  88, 102,  80   # 201.88.102.1
    .word  11, 148, 163, 170,  80   # 146.163.170.80
    .word  12, 193,  77,  77,  10   # 193.77.77.10

.text
.globl main

main:      

la $a0, IP_ROUTING_TABLE
lw $s0, ($a0)
lw $s1 4($a0)
lw $s2, 8($a0)
lw $s3, 12($a0)
lw $s4, 16($a0)



li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, MESSAGE14
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, MESSAGE14
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, MESSAGE14
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s3
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, MESSAGE14
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s4
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, MESSAGE14
syscall

addi $a0, 20

lw $s0, ($a0) #problem is here

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall




P_EXIT:        jr    $31
```

Sorry this became more lengthy than it probably should have been, I just wanted to make sure it was understood what was happening.  Thanks for the help.

Also, I have tried using the debugger and it hasn't helped me figure out the issue.

Comment: It makes little sense to store IP addresses with each byte unpacked to a word.  If you want separate bytes, you can load them that way with `lbu`, otherwise you'd want to store the whole IP address in a word.  So you might want `.byte`.  Assuming your MIPS is in big-endian mode, having the leading quad first is what you want. (You also don't need to store explicit index numbers; those can be *implicit* in an array fixed-length entries.  You want to index, not search.)

Comment: When you do `addi $a0, 20`, `$a0` is still holding `MESSAGE14`.  20 bytes forward from there is not a sensible position, and presumably not aligned.

Comment: I feel like you didn't quite understand that this was an assignment from an instructor, that is how it was given to me.  It also didn't make sense to me, but that is what my teacher.  However I appreciate your quick response, it has been two days since I asked my instructor for help.  I reloaded the table before the increment and it fixed the issue, so thank your I appreciate the help.

Comment: When I see the description "*word "table", Full of IP addresses*", I think of each IP address being stored in a separate word.  An IPv4 address is explicitly designed to fit in a single 32-bit value.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations).  This is the normal storage format for computers to work with IPv4 addresses in binary form, rather than ASCII digit-string dotted-quad form.  e.g. the format that's used as part of the struct for functions like https://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo.  (The functions take a length param because they also handle IPv6 and other formats)

Comment: If your teacher actually provided the whole block of lines like `.word   1, 147, 163, 255, 255   # 147.163.255.255`, then I guess you're meant to use that.  I assumed you made that up because you didn't say otherwise, and because it's totally weird, especially with the redundant index number (unless that number isn't always just in sequence).

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, I put ".word table" because it is essentially a table of data using the ".word"... function? descriptor?  type?  not sure what to call the spots where it says .ascizz and .word.  I will make sure to be a little more descriptive next time.  Also thank you for the additional information, I still have a lot to learn about how computers interpret data.

Comment: terminology: `.word` can be called a pseudo-instruction or assembler directive.  It does assemble bytes into the output (unlike most directives), so I think pseudo-instruction is the best term.  The GAS manual calls it a directive: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Word.html#Word.  But NASM (an x86 assembler) calls its equivalent `dd` a pseudo-instruction because it parses like an instruction: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2 along with some assemble-time-only things like `equ` that don't emit any bytes into the output file directly.