# Needing help debugging an assembly programs infinite loop

Tags: debugging, assembly, mips

I'll try to make this short.  I am running into an infinite loop issue with my program and even after trying to use the debugger I am having issues with an infinite loop.

The program I am trying to make is an assignment from my instructor, to sort through a table of IP addresses that use .word.  I have the program done about 95% the last issue I am having is when I type in 193.0.0.0, I run into this infinite loop, the structure for the loop is the same as the other two, which have no problems.  In this program, for a class C domain IP address to match the first 3 numbers of the IP Address need to match user input other wise continue onto the rest of the table. 
   The specific issue that is happening is when it finds a match for the first number and continues to try and match the second number, and then for the third number. If the second number or third number doesn't match it jumps back to the loop, but then gets trapped there, which shouldn't be happening.  At least, from what I can tell it shouldn't be.

The matching works beautifully, it is if it doesn't match that there is a problem, but again I am not sure why I am hoping that a fresh set of eyes will be able to help me see the issue.
   Also, sorry for any sloppiness in the code, and for it being kind of lengthy, it is rather simple though.  I appreciate the help.

```
.data

MESSAGE1: .asciiz "Enter an IP address\n"
MESSAGE2: .asciiz "First: "
MESSAGE3: .asciiz "Second: "
MESSAGE4: .asciiz "Third: "
MESSAGE5: .asciiz "Fourth: "
MESSAGE6: .asciiz "The IP address you entered: "
MESSAGE7: .asciiz "."
MESSAGE8: .asciiz "\nClass A address\n"
MESSAGE9: .asciiz "\nClass B address\n"
MESSAGE10: .asciiz "\nClass C address\n"
MESSAGE11: .asciiz "\nClass D address\n"
MESSAGE12: .asciiz "\nInvalid domain class\n"
MESSAGE13: .asciiz "\nProgram successfully completed . . .\n"
MESSAGE14: .asciiz "\n"
MESSAGE15: .asciiz "Matching domain found at line: "
MESSAGE16: .asciiz "Matching domain was NOT found . . . \n"
ERROROVER: .asciiz "The entered number is larger than 255.\n"
ERRORUNDER: .asciiz "The entered number is smaller than 0.\n"





IP_ROUTING_TABLE_SIZE:
    .word   10

IP_ROUTING_TABLE:
    # line #, x.x.x.x -------------------------------------
    .word   0, 146,  92, 255, 255   # 146.92.255.255
    .word   1, 147, 163, 255, 255   # 147.163.255.255
    .word   2, 201,  88,  88,  90   # 201.88.88.90
    .word   3, 182, 151,  44,  56   # 182.151.44.56
    .word   4,  24, 125, 100, 100   # 24.125.100.100
    .word   5, 146, 163, 140,  80   # 146.163.170.80
    .word   6, 146, 163, 147,  80   # 146.163.147.80
    .word  10, 201,  88, 102,  80   # 201.88.102.1
    .word  11, 148, 163, 170,  80   # 146.163.170.80
    .word  12, 193,  77,  77,  10   # 193.77.77.10

.text
.globl main

main:       
    la $a1, IP_ROUTING_TABLE_SIZE
    lw $t9, ($a1)



    li $t7, 255 #top limit

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE1  #asking for the address
    syscall
FIRST:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE2 #first number
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t0, $v0  #saving input for later use.

    bgt $t0, $t7, thi1 # if greater than 255
    blt $t0,$zero, tlo1 # if less than

SECOND:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE3 # second number
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t1, $v0  #saving input

    bgt $t1, $t7, thi2 #if greater than
    blt $t1,$zero, tlo2 #if less than
THIRD:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE4 #third number
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t2, $v0 #saving input

    bgt $t2, $t7, thi3 #if greater than
    blt $t2,$zero, tlo3 #if less than

FOURTH:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE5 #fourth number
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t3, $v0 #saving input

    bgt $t3, $t7, thi4 #if greater than
    blt $t3,$zero, tlo4 #if less than


Address:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE6
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE7
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE7
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE7
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t3
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE14
    syscall


    j ClassSort




P_EXIT: 

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE13
    syscall



    jr    $31 #end of module main
################################################################        


ClassSort:

     #check for class A

     li $t5, 127
     blt $t0, $t5, ClassA

     #check for class B

     li $t5, 191
     blt $t0, $t5, ClassB

     #check for class C
     li $t5, 223
     blt $t0, $t5, ClassC

     #check for class D
     li $t5, 239
     blt $t0, $t5, ClassD

     #Invalid otherwise
     bgt $t0, $t5, Invalid

thi1:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERROROVER #too High
    syscall
    j FIRST
tlo1:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERRORUNDER #too Low
    syscall
    j FIRST
thi2:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERROROVER #too High
    syscall
    j SECOND
tlo2:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERRORUNDER #too Low
    syscall
    j SECOND
thi3:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERROROVER #too High
    syscall
    j THIRD
tlo3:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERRORUNDER #too Low
    syscall 
    j THIRD
thi4:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERROROVER #too High
    syscall
    j FOURTH
tlo4:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ERRORUNDER #too Low
    syscall
    j FOURTH



ClassA:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE8
    syscall 

    li $t5, 0 #reset offset
    li $t6, 0 #reset counter
ALOOP:

    la $a0, IP_ROUTING_TABLE      #load table
    add $a0, $a0, $t5             #add current offset

    lw $s0, ($a0)  #load words at offsets
    lw $s1,4($a0)
    lw $s2,8($a0)
    lw $s3,12($a0)
    lw $s4,16($a0)

    beq $t0, $s1, LINENUMBER #branch if match

    addi $t5, 20 #increment offset
    addi $t6, 1  #increment counter

    beq $t6, $t9, NOMAT
    j ALOOP


ClassB:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE9
    syscall

    li $t5, 0 #reset offset
    li $t6, 0 #reset counter
BLOOP:  

    la $a0, IP_ROUTING_TABLE #load table
    add $a0, $a0, $t5 #add current offset

    lw $s0, ($a0)  #load words at offsets
    lw $s1,4($a0)
    lw $s2,8($a0)
    lw $s3,12($a0)
    lw $s4,16($a0)


    addi $t5, 20 #increment offset
    addi $t6, 1 #increment counter

    beq $t0, $s1, MATCHSECOND #branch if match

    beq $t6, $t9, NOMAT #branch if no match
    j BLOOP

#############################################################
 #error is  some where here, I think that it is down in MATCHSECOND2
ClassC:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE10
    syscall

    li $t5, 0 #reset offset
    li $t6, 0 #reset counter
CLOOP:      
    la $a0, IP_ROUTING_TABLE #load table

    add $a0, $a0, $t5 #add current offset/ the next line in table

    lw $s0, ($a0)  #load words at offsets
    lw $s1,4($a0)
    lw $s2,8($a0)
    lw $s3,12($a0)
    lw $s4,16($a0)


    addi $t5, 20 #increment offset
    addi $t6, 1 #increment counter


    beq $t0, $s1, MATCHSECOND2 #branch if match


    beq $t6, $t9, NOMAT #branch if it reaches the end of the table.



    j CLOOP  #end of ClassC
####################################################
ClassD:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE11
    syscall
    j P_EXIT

Invalid: 
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE12
    syscall
    j P_EXIT

NOMAT:  #no match
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE16
    syscall

    j P_EXIT

LINENUMBER:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, MESSAGE15
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall

    j P_EXIT

MATCHSECOND:
    beq $s2, $t1, LINENUMBER

    j BLOOP
################################################
#belong to classC/CLOOP
MATCHSECOND2:
    beq $s2, $t1, MATCHTHIRD #if second number matches, branch to test third
#if it doesn't match loop back to top
    j CLOOP

MATCHTHIRD:
#provide the line of matching address if all three numbers
    beq $s3, $t2, LINENUMBER 
    #if it doesn't match loop back to top
    j CLOOP
 ###############################################
```

Comment: Why are the IP addresses (for matching) stored in this weird 4x word format, when the whole point of IPv4 address was, that it fits into 32 bits (one word)? Blasphemy... :)

Comment: @Ped7g: that's exactly what I said on another question that has the exact same silly table with each byte expanded to a word, and with those redundant index numbers that make the element size not a power of 2.  [Trying to traverse a .word "Table" in MIPS Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53324242).  Apparently the table was provided as part of an assignment.

Comment: @PeterCordes some lectors should be lectured... :)

Comment: Hello @PeterCordes,  this is actually that same person that you helped out, lol. I couldn't login to the previous account after that question, so I had to make another.  This is in fact the same stupid project, where the teacher provided the table that way.  I believe his intent is to make a project where we learn how to store and access the data within tables such as these, but also make it relate-able... still confuses the crap out of me and my class.  But that is also because he hasn't really shown us how to actually write assembly code.  Had to teach myself everything, which isn't much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's flawed logic in the `CLOOP` (and not only there), when the first digit is "match" and second is "no-match", the check for table size is skipped, thus the loop may get out of IP table data.

---

Other problems:

```
     #check for class D
     li $t5, 239
     blt $t0, $t5, ClassD

     #Invalid otherwise
     bgt $t0, $t5, Invalid
```

This doesn't cover value 240. You can do `b Invalid` without any test.

---

Some other suggestions:

If you would preserve `$ra` (return address from `main`), you would be able to use `jal subroutine` to re-use some generic parts of code, like `thiX` and `tloX` parts of code .. or the whole request of input values can be like one loop using just arguments to display different prompts and store the values in array (or single register, see below).

And IPv4 addresses are 32 bit values (the reason why "255" is maximum for particular value), and they are exploited as such.

For example sub-network matching uses masking, i.e. if sub-network `160.120.0.0` (that's like value `0xA0780000`) has mask 255.255.0.0 (that's like value `0xFFFF0000`), then to decide if particular IP a.b.c.d is part of that sub-network, you do

```
is_part_of_subnet = ((IP & mask) == subnetwork_IP);
```

Which in assembly may look like

```
    # fake init for example
    li    $t0, 0xA0780000  # subnet address 160.120.0.0
    li    $t1, 0xFFFF0000  # subnet mask 255.255.0.0
    li    $t2, 0x12345678  # some/any IP address
          # (must start with 0xA078... to trigger positive match)

    # sub-network match-check
    # mask-out parts of IP address which are not significant for test
    and   $t3, $t2, $t1    # this will clear third/fourth value to zero
    beq   $t3, $t0, IP_is_part_of_sub_network
    # IP is not part of subnetwork (first two values are different)
    ...

IP_is_part_of_sub_network:
    ...
```

Line number in table should be rather calculated value from traversal of the array, than part of the stored value.

After those two things put together, the IP table may be actually compressed down into single word per line, like:

```
.word 0x925CFFFF  # 146.92.255.255
```

To make `beq` test work, you then should mask both values by the class mask to make only the significant parts of IP address survive to the compare...

(I'm not networking expert, so I may have flipped the sub-net mask definition, maybe it's 0.0.255.255, but then the code will flip the mask for the needs of `and` instruction, or it will use mask like this, but use instead `or` to set up the bit values in lower positions to 255, from programming point of view you just have to make sure you are using the correct and/or/flip sequence to get the correct results)

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess this part needs more clarification.  Testing for a match on the first number, if it matches it goes to the second number that makes a comparison, but if the comparison comes back untrue it goes back to CLOOP which then reloads the table,  adds the offset (which was already incremented by 20, it also is loading the next line) and continues reading the info.  The check for "NOMAT" is for if it hits the end of the table when there is no "particular match".  This is my fault I was trying to shorten the post, for a class C IP address to match the first 3 numbers have to match.

Comment: I appreciate your help, and if there is anything else that needs more clarification please don't hesitate to ask.  To me it makes sense, at least logically it makes sense.  Also I am going to add a few more comments to make sure that the intent of the program is clear.  It is a program from a teacher that wants this table.  Also thank you for the additional information that you provided on working with IP addresses in assembly.

Comment: ..... actually I think I owe you an apology and a thank you, I changed around the no match check to a little higher in the loop and moved the increments to bellow the check and it fixed the issue, so thank you.  I think the issue was the fact that I was testing for the very last value in the table and the offset incremented past the table.  I don't know why I didn't see that in the debugger, thank you for the help.

Comment: If there is match on first value, the `beq $t6, $t9, NOMAT` is not executed, only `j CLOOP`, so the (updated) offset into table will be actually used to read data, but that may be already beyond original table. It still a bit surprises me that it actually did "trap", I would expect it to run into some zeroed memory area, failing any matching and doing the table-size test eventually... oh wait, it's `beq`!! Whenever possible, I write my size tests as `ptr < end()`, not `ptr != end()`, so even if due to some reason ptr is something bogus like `end()+1`, the test will terminate the loop.

Comment: @Tanktastic it's called "defensive" programming, not trusting much even inner state of code, and writing each subroutine as robust as possible (but staying reasonable), in similar case it may save and recover from some internal bugs, which may be good or bad in production (depends what you are working on, you don't want the bank payment routine to recover and finish payment when it failed on digital signature check, but you don't want the car ABS to stop working completely because specific value "140" fall through all tests to wrong "invalid state" code branch).

Comment: @Tanktastic and probably final comment... even if the data table format is horrible, you can still internally convert it to proper IPv4 table before doing your part of code, the lector will have then to accept it, if it's runtime conversion at beginning. Also learning how to bit-mask value before tests to achieve correct logic is something useful for programming student (the principle does apply in various other languages, like C/C++/C#/Java/JavaScript/...). And finally it would simplify your 1/2/3 value tests into single test (like 1 val), which would save you from the wrong loop logic :D ...

Comment: And one more thing... about learning asm yourself, etc... actually I don't believe topic as large as programming can be learned by just going to lectures and doing what lector tells you (even if they would lecture you in better quality and depth). That's not sufficient. Your own experience, and burning at least hundred+ hours programming yourself is absolutely essential. So even if you will finish first working version of this, get back to some MIPS tutorials, read about subroutines, check other working examples, and try to take fresh look on your code, if you can write new variant of it...